# AWS Dynamo DB Object Mapper Error

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am trying to query my AWS Dynamo DB table "UserCreds" via swift code. I have first defined a class and then mapped it to Dynamo DB table. Then I am calling AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression() to search for a row on this table.
but the program keeps crashing with following error:

"ViewController11viewDidLoadFS0_FT_T_L_11DDBTableRow dynamoDBTableName]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x102ec3d40]"

I have also ensured that I have correct credentials setup in the AppDelegate file. Any insight into the reasons why this could be failing would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Below is what the code looks like:

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    class DDBTableRow :AWSDynamoDBObjectModel {

        var UserIdentifier:String?
        var UserFullName:String?


        class func dynamoDBTableName() -> String! {
            return "UserCreds"
        }

        class func hashKeyAttribute() -> String! {
            return "UserIdentifier"
        }

        class func rangeKeyAttribute() -> String! {
            return "UserFullName"
        }

        //MARK: NSObjectProtocol hack
        override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
            return super.isEqual(object)
        }

        override func `self`() -> Self {
            return self
        }
    }


    //SEARCH FOR A ROW
    let dynamoDBObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper()

    let queryExpression = AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression()
    queryExpression.indexName = "UserIdentifier-UserFullName-index"
    queryExpression.hashKeyAttribute = "UserIdentifier"
    queryExpression.hashKeyValues = "1234"
    queryExpression.scanIndexForward = true

    dynamoDBObjectMapper.query(DDBTableRow.self, expression: queryExpression).continueWithExecutor(AWSExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), withBlock: { (task:AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
        if (task.error != nil) {
            print("Error: \(task.error)")

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Failed to query a test table.", message: task.error.description, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            })
            alertController.addAction(okAction)
            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            if (task.result != nil) {
                print(task.result)
            }
            print("Performing Segue")
        }
        return nil
    })

}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are accessing Dynamo from the app directly instead of consuming it through an api?  With an api you can handle the Db interactions and return simple objects to your app. Also I find it easier to make backend changes to my APIs without having to send a new version to my users.

Comment: have you got solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Is it sensible to have your DDBTableRow class definition inside the viewDidLoad() method inside the ViewController class?